# Changing icon for file (extensions) without changing other file icons openend by same application (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, icons

I use Notepad++ for many files, like c, c++, txt, etc.

I have a problem changing some icons for certain files opened by Notepad++ without also changing the icons for other files opened by Notepad++.

For instance, I use Notepad++ as default for **.py** files and **.txt** files. If I change the icon for the **.py** extension, it also changes the **.txt** icon to that, and vice versa. (The programs I used for changing them: **FileTypesMan** and **Types**; same results.)

For some files I was able to do it, like for **.c** and **.cpp** files. They have distinct icons, but also use Notepad++ as the default application.

How can I change the associated icon for a file (extension), independently of the default application and without affecting other files which use the same application as default?

Comment: Three years and no answer is really deeply disappoting. Have the same problems myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) from excelent Nirsoft?

It's a small application that can allow you to set specific icon per file extension. I think it should be able to change the icon without messing with the default program.